# MailConnectException when sending through google smtp spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, email, smtp

I've been getting the error below with my google smtp in my spring boot app.

```
Exception in thread "pool-5-thread-1" org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 25; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
```

Below is my configuration. I am doing the same process in my web app, but sometimes I get an email but most of the time I encounter an error.

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.username=emailAdress@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=appPassword
spring.mail.transport.protocol=smtp
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.port=587 (also tried 465)
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true (tried true and false)
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.debug=true
```

Not sure what the problem is and I can say I exhausted all the possible previous question like before.

Hope someone can enlighten me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

this is how I implimented email sender in one of my project. Please have a look.

```
public void send(String from, String to, String subject, String body) throws MessagingException {
            final JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender = getJavaMailSender();
            Properties prop = javaMailSender.getJavaMailProperties();         
            Session session = Session.getInstance(prop, null);
            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(javaMailSender.getUsername()));
            msg.setSubject(subject);
            msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to, false));
    
            MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");
            MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart.setContent(body, "text/html");
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
            msg.setContent(multipart);
            msg.setSentDate(new Date());
            javaMailSender.send(msg);
        }
     
    
        private JavaMailSenderImpl getJavaMailSender() {
            JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
            mailSender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
            mailSender.setPort(587);
            mailSender.setUsername(username);
            mailSender.setPassword(password);
            Properties props = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
            props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);
            props.put("mail.smtp.timeout", 60000);
            props.put("mail.smtp.connectiontimeout", 60000);
            props.put("mail.smtp.writetimeout", 60000);
            return mailSender;
        }
```